# FPGA HDMI graphics, higher level flow for basic desktop

Tags: fpga, hdmi

I am interested in using an FPGA which has HDMI output and mouse and keyboard input to do a primitive GUI/desktop. The FPGA will have some processing happening in the background, and I basically want to create a graphical plot of this. I also want a window the user can click to change some system settings related to that background processing.

So far, most of the FPGA HDMI tutorials are very low level: delivering pixel information/HSYNC/VSYNC... just the lowest level interface. I think I can intuit that there is some RAM/sequencer block attached to this low level interface that provides the sequencing to draw pixels in the correct order.

What types of blocks exist for the rest of the flow: What fills out the RAM? Is it as simple as having a MicroBlaze handling every single pixel, or something more sophisticated?

Comment: FPGAs are not well suited for the task you describe. Processors and operating systems do that. The FPGA usually implements the low level functions you have seen. So in short: OS -> display buffer -> FPGA -> HDMI driver -> display.

Comment: Think of the FPGA as more of a basic graphics card... *just* the graphics card, for what you want, you need the whole rest of the computer (which you *can* build in the FPGA, but it's really hard). If you must use an FPGA, check out the Xilinx Zynq or the Altera (Intel) Cylcone V SE, both have an onboard dual core ARM cpu, so they're both only a power supply and a stck of RAM away from being a full computer.